# Java writing to a text file not working properly

Tags: java

The Java application that I support is logging some details in a flat file. the problem I face  some times is that, the entry is very low compared to the previous day. This entry is most essential because our reports are generated based on the file. I went thro code for writing I couldn't figure out any issues. the method which is writing is sync method.

Any suggestions? I can also provide the code for you is you may need?

```
 public synchronized void log (String connID, String hotline, String callerType,
        String cli, String lastMenu, String lastInput,
        String status, String reason)
   {
    //String absoluteFP = LOG_LOC + ls + this.getFilename();

    //PrintWriter pw = this.getPrintWriter(absoluteFP, true, true);

    try
    {
        pw.print (this.getDateTime ()+ ","+connID +","+hotline+","+callerType+","+ cli+"," +   lastMenu + "," + lastInput + "," + status + "," + reason);               


        //end 1006
        pw.print (ls);
        pw.flush ();
        //pw.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace ();
        return;
    }
}

private synchronized PrintWriter getPrintWriter (String absoluteFileName,
        boolean append, boolean autoFlush)
{
    try
    {
        //set absolute filepath
        File folder = new File (absoluteFileName).getParentFile ();//2009-01-23

        File f = new File (absoluteFileName);

        if (!folder.exists ())//2009-01-23
        {
            //System.out.println ("Call Detailed Record folder NOT FOUND! Creating a new);     
            folder.mkdirs ();

            //System.out.println ("Configure log folder");
            this.setHiddenFile (LOG_LOC);//set tmp directory to hidden folder

            if (!f.exists ())
            {
                //System.out.println ("Creating a new Call Detailed Record...");//2009-01-23

                f.createNewFile ();//2009-01-23

                               }
        }
        else
        {
            if (!f.exists ())
            {
                //System.out.println ("Creating a new Call Detailed Record...");//2009-01-23

                f.createNewFile ();//2009-01-23


            }
        }

        FileOutputStream tempFOS = new FileOutputStream (absoluteFileName, append);
        if (tempFOS != null)
        {
            return new PrintWriter (tempFOS, autoFlush);
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace ();
        return null;
    }
}

          /**
             * Set the given absolute file path as a hidden file.
        * @param absoluteFile String
      */
     private void setHiddenFile (String absoluteFile)
       {
    //set hidden file
    //2009-01-22, KC
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime ();
    absoluteFile = absoluteFile.substring (0, absoluteFile.length () - 1);//2009-01-23
    try
    {
      System.out.println (rt.exec ("attrib +H " + "\"" + absoluteFile +        "\"").getInputStream ().toString ());
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace ();
    }
}

private String getDateTime ()
{
    //2011-076-09, KC-format up to milliseconds to prevent duplicate PK in CDR table.
    //return DateUtils.now ("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    return DateUtils.now ("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss:SSS");
    //end 0609
}

private String getFilename ()
{
    ///return "CDR_" + port + ".dat";//2010-10-01
    return port + ".dat";//2010-10-01
}

public void closePW ()
{
    if (pw != null)
    {
        pw.close ();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure log entries are really missing (maybe there just was not much activity for that day)? If you use an established logging library (and you probably should) it is very unlikely that they would get this basic functionality wrong.

Comment: I have no idea what you want to happen. Please post some relevant code so that we have somewhere to start on this.

Comment: @Thio and Aditya I have updated my post with my code.

Comment: @ArunKumar Where is there code?

Comment: Sorry just edited and re-posted.

Comment: @ArunKumar You should just edit this post to add the code, not start a new one.

Comment: @Hunter McMillen my apology Was facing some issues while posting my code. Now you can see.

Comment: why not use log4j instead of writing something of your own ? you can manage the log's format if thats what the concern is.

Comment: there doesn't seem to be any evident problem with the code shown here, are there any patterns around the problem (anything you see in your applications logs) ?

Comment: You've created a `FileOutputStream`, but aren't closing that stream. Close that stream and try again. That might be causing the problem

Comment: @aishwaryaThe problem is that developer has left the company. I am supporting this project now. I am not sure y he did not use log4j. I dont see any patterns either from the files. But users are comparing our report with other reports and there seems to be some differences in our report. But when I compare yesterdays log and todays log size there seems to be some difference, also users are saying that some times reports are ok but some times the values seems to be low.

Comment: Do you think there is any threads issue? Since the threads are controlled by os? Every day around 50K to 70K entries will be recorded in these files.

Comment: @Varun Achar i will check on that. Just to clarify if that's the case wouldn't be creating problem all along right? The problem I face is some times its ok but some times entry is very less!

Comment: You may have a file handler not being closed problem. You should close the file handler, e.g., FileOutputStream, in the same scope, e.g. same method, whenever you open it. If you don't, then you need to be very careful expecially when you are using in the multhithreading environment.

Comment: @gigadot I tried closing it keeps throwing unreachable statement error. Also  I found out that in log method printWriter(pw) was not closed after writing do you think that might be the problem? Also suggest where i should close the file handler as its returning a printWriter object which is writing into the file.

Comment: @ArunKumar: Messages are getting logged sometime because the garbage collector kicks in at some intervals and closes the `FileOutStream`. This then allows messages to be logged again. You're getting the unreachable error since you have a return statement in both the if & else blocks. You'll have to take the `PrintWriter` and `FileOutStreamWriter` out of the `getPrintWriter` put it where you usually call the `getPrintWriter()`. Then you'll be able to `close` the streams correctly. `getPrintWriter` should only ensure file exists, so rename it to `ensureFileExistance`.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I will modify accordingly..

Answer (score 1):

You've created a `FileOutputStream`, but aren't closing that stream. Close that stream and try again. That might be causing the problem.

Messages are getting logged sometime because the garbage collector kicks in at some intervals and closes the `FileOutStream`. This then allows messages to be logged again. You're getting the unreachable error since you have a `return` statement in both the `if` &  `else` blocks. You'll have to take the `PrintWriter` and `FileOutStreamWriter`  out of the `getPrintWriter` put it where you usually call the `getPrintWriter()`. Then you'll be able to close  the streams correctly. `getPrintWriter` should only ensure file exists, so rename it to `ensureFileExistance`

Comment: Just a final clarification, suppose I am separating those two to two different methods do I have to make my folder exists method to be a  sync method as well?

Comment: not required. `file.mkDirs()` will fail, but won't give an exception. It will be safe.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use Apache Common IO, try this:

```
public synchronized void log(String connID, String hotline, String callerType,
        String cli, String lastMenu, String lastInput,
        String status, String reason) {
    String absoluteFP = LOG_LOC + ls + this.getFilename();
    File file = new File(absoluteFP);
    String message = this.getDateTime() + "," + connID + "," + hotline + "," + callerType + "," + cli + "," + lastMenu + "," + lastInput + "," + status + "," + reason;
    try {
        // note that you must explicitly add new line character if you want the line to end with newline
        FileUtils.write(file, message + "\n", "UTF-8", true);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace ();
    }
}
```

In Common IO 2.1, you can append a file that you are writting to. You can now get rid of the `closePW` and `getPrintwriter` and since the log method is `synchronized`, the file can be written one at a time from the same object. However, if you try to write the same file from different object at the same time, you will end up having overwritting problem.

Also, Common IO create the missing parent folder for you automatically. There is no need to explicitly check and create the folder.